# javascript how to parseInt the values of an array to sum them all up

Tags: javascript, arrays, parseint

How do I parseInt the numbers in an array to add them up. Where would I add the parseInt? SO i can then take the arrays summed values and divide by the .length value of the array. Would it be done in where the array is first stated or in the function for the sum? It has not been working for me

```
<script>
    var studentArr = new Array();
    var scoreArr = new Array();

    function enter() {

        var studentName = document.getElementById("inp").value;
        studentArr.push(studentName);

        var stuval = "";

        for(i=0; i < studentArr.length; i++)
        {
            stuval = stuval + studentArr[i] + "<br/>";
        }

        document.getElementById("iop").innerHTML = stuval;

        var studentScore = document.getElementById("inps").value;
        scoreArr.push(studentScore);

        var scoreval = "";

        for(i=0; i < scoreArr.length; i++)
        {
            scoreval = scoreval + scoreArr[i] + "<br/>";
        }



    }

    function summ() {

        var grade;
        var average;
        var sum = parseInt(scoreArr.valueOf());

        if (scoreArr.valueOf() == 70) {

                grade = "C";
                document.getElementById("opo").innerHTML = grade;
        }

        if (scoreArr.valueOf() == 80) {

                grade = "B";
                document.getElementById("opo").innerHTML = grade;
        }

        if (scoreArr.valueOf() == 90) {

                grade = "A";
                document.getElementById("opo").innerHTML = grade;
        }

        scoreArr.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
        document.getElementById("hop").innerHTML = "Max Score is: <br>" + scoreArr[0];

        scoreArr.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
        document.getElementById("lop").innerHTML = "Min Score is: <br>" + scoreArr[0];

        average = sum / scoreArr.length;
        document.getElementById("aop").innerHTML = average;

    }

</script>
```

Comment: [MDN parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: Thank you, that is where I was guiding myself but I am a begginer in javascript and unfortunately do not understand how to apply it.I tried exactly how it is displayed there with the .reduce and it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
sum=0;
for (i=1; i<randomArray.length; i++){
    sum += parseInt(randomArray[i]);
}
result = sum / randomArray.length;
```

Comment: Tell me if it's what you were looking for

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to achieve. Very much appreciated!